# Nodejs moment not able to convert string to date

Tags: node.js, momentjs

When I tried to run following code its returning `Moment<Invalid date>`

```
const moment = require('moment')
const date = "20210519"
const dateObj = moment(date, "yyyyMMdd",true)
console.log(dateObj)
```

How to convert this string to date object?

Comment: It looks like you have an issue with your pattern. Instead of `yyyyMMdd` you should use "YYYYMMDD"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the format string from "yyyyMMdd" to "YYYYMMDD" should fix the issue:

```js
const date = "20210519"
const dateObj = moment(date, "YYYYMMDD",true)
console.log(dateObj)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Some more parsing details are here:
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/